# How can I stay in one Java class until I'm ready to exit

Tags: java, class

This is for a homework assignment.  I'm making a basic banking app, that has an admin class.  The admin class is supposed to perform different functions.  I have the log-in part made, and I can get the menu to call the admin class.  Its just that when I perform one of the functions in the Admin class, it exits back out to the menu class.  I want to be able to perform all actions in the Admin class until I exit. I put it in a do while loop, but that lead to an infinite loop.  I'm trying to figure out my next best step.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Menu {

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Bank bank = new Bank();
boolean exit;
private int choice;
private static String Password = "welcome1";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.runMenu();
}

public void runMenu( ) {
    printHeader();
    while(!exit) {
        printMenu();
        int choice = getInput();
        performAction(choice);
    }
}

private void printHeader() {
    System.out.println("*****");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Java Bank");
    System.out.println("*****");
}
private void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("Select Option");
    System.out.println("1.  Open an Account");
    System.out.println("2.  Close an Account");
    System.out.println("3.  Deposit");
    System.out.println("4.  WithDraw");
    System.out.println("5.  Administrator Function");
    //System.out.println("0.  Exit");

    private  void  adminLog() {

    Administrator admin = new Administrator() ;
    System.out.println("Please enter password");
    Scanner inn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String PW = inn.nextLine();

    if ( PW.equals(Password))
    {
        admin.adminChoice2();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Verification Failed.  Please Enter correct password.");
```

**The Admin Class**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Administrator extends Menu {   
//private int numberOfAccounts;
//private int cashammount;
double savingsInterest = 0.05;
double checkingInterest = 0.05;
double cdInterest = 0.05;

public void me() {
    System.out.println("TesT");
}

public void options( ) {
    System.out.println("Pleae select an option");
}
```

Comment: *I put it in a do while loop, but that lead to an infinite loop.* - there has to be a way for the `exit` boolean value to change within the loop.

Comment: if (choice == 0) { exit = true; } else { performAction(choice); }

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @iluxa's comment. Here is a more in depth code version of what he is trying to say... (I think)

```java
while (true) {
    String option = scanner.nextLine();

    if (option.equals("0")) {
        break;
    } else if (option.equals("1")) {
        // Preform Option 1 case.
    } else if //...
}
```